# Understanding objects with local state -- Scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme, mit-scheme

i'm studying for my scheme final and objects with local state has always been a tough subject.

Here is a question from my final exam that i need help on.

```
(define (make-incrementer n)
  (let ((old 0)
        (new 0))
    (lambda ()
      (cond ((< new n) 
             (set! old new)
             (set! new (+ new 1))
             old)
            (else 
             (set! old 0)
             (set! new 1)
             old)))))

(define a (make-incrementer 3))
(define b (make-incrementer 3))
(define c a)

; 1) (a)
; 2) (a)
```

why when `a` is called the second time it returns 1? I'm looking at the code and the `n` we give it is always 3. So wouldn't it always do the `else` case?

Comment: Sometimes understanding is facilitated by code layout because that makes the scope of different names **plainly obvious**.

Comment: @GoZoner Indeed, thank goodness for C-M-\ in emacs

Comment: And 'M-x untabify' when posting to SO

Comment: im running this on windows unfortunately so i dont have emacs.

Comment: @user2036503: GNU Emacs is available for Windows, last I looked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of closures! This is a textbook example of how closures in Scheme work.

So `make-counter` returns a function that has 3 variables that it captures from it's enclosing environment: `n`, `old`, `new`. In this case, the starting environment looks something like

```
_name_|_value_
 n    | 3
 old  | 0
 new  | 1
```

On each invocation, it increments `old` and `new` and wraps them around if they're greater than `n`. Because it's using `set!`, this incrementing is mutating the variables in the lambda's environment, but since these variables are captured from the surrounding environment, they are changed for all future calls as well.

That's why you get different returns even with the same input.

If this seems like witchcraft, you can think of it like objects in more common languages:

Eg Python:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, n, m):
        self.n = n
        self.m = m
    def count(self):
        self.n += 1
        if self.n == self.m:
           self.n = 1
        return self.n-1

f = Foo(0, 2)

f.count() # 1
f.count() # 0
```

This is the same basic idea except here we're being a bit more explicit about where the environment is coming from, `self`. In Scheme, we mimic this with the lambda capturing the surrounding variables.

For more, check out [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-19.html#%_chap_3)

Comment: the main thing i dont get is , doesnt old and new have to be greater than 3 for the incrementing set to work?

Comment: @user2036503 yes, but they're being incremented, `(set! new (+ 1 new))`

Comment: im probably missing something VERY OBVIOUS. sorry for that. But for the incrementing  to work doesnt new have to be greater than n. But n equals 3 and the initial new equals 1 so it never increments.

Comment: No worries, is it starting to make some sense?

Comment: sort of maybe something is wrong with how i inputed (a) and then (a) again.  But shouldnt it return 0 then 0. Or am i wrong?

Comment: You're wrong :) When it mutates the variables in the scope *above* the lambda, it's mutated for all future calls to the lambda. That means that the second time you call it, `new` will be 2 not 1. It will "remember" the change

Comment: wow. I am sorry . The sign is actually a < symbol. Not a > symbol. I totally understand now. This whole time i thought it was new > n. but its new < n.

Comment: Haha well we're good then? If so, click the green check by my answer to mark the question as solved

Comment: yeah. sorry to waste ur time i woudlve totally understood it when i saw it, but i mixed < with >.

Comment: Don't worry about it, happy to help

Comment: @user2036503 it is not an uncommon mistake, believe it or not. you read `(< new n)` as "is less than new, n" instead of "is less, new, than n". it happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples, that might help with the concept of capturing state:

```
(define (always x) 
  (lambda rest x))
(define always-true (always #t))
(always-true #f)
-> #t

(define (add-n n) 
  (lambda (m)
    (+ n m)))
(define add-1 (add-n 1))
(add-1 10)
-> 11

(define (complement predicate)
  (lambda (x)
    (not (predicate x)))
(define not-positive? (complement positive?))
(not-positive? -1)
-> #t
```

Next is an example where the captured state, in this case `l`, is mutated.  This is similar to your case where `new` and `old` are captures and modified.

```
(define (nexting l)
  (lambda ()
    (if (null? l)
        '()
        (let ((answer (car l)))
          (set! l (cdr l))
          answer))))
(define next-user (nexting '(Alice Bob David)))
(next-user)
-> Alice
(next-user)
-> Bob
(next-user)
-> David
(next-user)
'()
```